# Using CSS to re-order division elements

Tags: css

I have a website I am trying to extend to be more usable on tablets and phones. I'm using stylesheets with media selectors in the HTML

My HTML is like this

```
  <div id="page">
    <div id='header'> ... </div>
    <div id='navigation'> ... </nav>
    <div id='content'> ... </div>
    <div id='footer'> ... </div>
  </div>
```

My desktop layout is like this

```
┌───────────────────#page──────────────────────┐
│ ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ │
│ │ header                                   │ │
│ └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ │
│ ┌──────. ┌─────────────────────────────────┐ │
│ │nav   │ │ content                         │ │
: :      : :                                 : :
│ │      │ │                                 │ │
│ └──────┘ │                                 │ │
│          └─────────────────────────────────┘ │
│ ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐ │
│ │footer                                    │ │
│ └──────────────────────────────────────────┘ │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

My `desktop.css` floats the `#navigation` left and sets a width & left-margin on
the `#content` to keep it clear of `#navigation`. This is a fixed width layout - `#page` has a fixed `width:55em` and `margin: 2em auto` so it stays centered in the window.
So far so good.

I want my phone layout to be like this, with `#navigation` relocated between `#content` and `#footer`.

```
┌───────────#page──────────────┐
│ ┌──────────────────────────┐ │
│ │header                    │ │
│ └──────────────────────────┘ │
│ ┌──────────────────────────┐ │
│ │content                   │ │
: :                          : :
│ │                          │ │
│ └──────────────────────────┘ │
│ ┌──────────────────────────┐ │
│ │navigation                │ │
│ └──────────────────────────┘ │
│ ┌──────────────────────────┐ │
│ │footer                    │ │
│ └──────────────────────────┘ │
└──────────────────────────────┘
```

And I want this to be a more fluid layout that squishes around nicely as the user resizes the window (or to fit various sized phone screens etc).

I tried absolute positioning for `#navigation` but it then doesn't scroll off the bottom for long content. The content is variable from page to page (obvs).

I could obviously change the order of divs in the HTML but I was wondering if it is possible to do this reordering of divisions in CSS (as in current-ish phones).

---

#### Minimal snippet with `desktop.css`

*(added following request in comments)*

```css
body { 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
  background: grey;
}

#page {
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 55em;
  margin: 2em auto;
}

#header, #navigation, #content, #footer {
  background: white;
  padding: 0.7em;
}
#navigation, #content, #footer {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

#header { 
  font-size: 3em; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  color: green;
}

#navigation {
  float:left;
  width: 18%; 
}
#navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#content {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 24%
}
#content td:first-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}
#content td {
  padding: 0 0.5em 0.2em 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#footer {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>layout & font-size tests</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page">
  
      <div id="header">
        Site Name
      </div>

      <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li>Here</li>
          <li>There</li>
          <li>Somewhere</li>
          <li>Elsewhere</li>
          <li>Hither</li>
          <li>Thither</li>
          <li>Yon</li>
          <li>Beyond</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div id="content">
        <h1>Welcome to Site Name!</h1>
        <h2>Diary</h2>
        <table class="calendar">
          <tr><td>Jun 18 2015</td><td>18:30</td><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Jul 01 2015</td><td>09:00</td><td>consectetur adipisicing elit</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Aug 09 2015</td><td>18:00</td>
              <td>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
                  magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud   
                  exercitation exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip</td></tr>
        </table>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p>
          dolor sit amet,  consectetur adipisicing      
          elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
          magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud   
          exercitation exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip 
          ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor  
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillium dolore 
          eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p>
          dolor sit amet,  consectetur adipisicing      
          elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
          magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud   
          exercitation exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip 
          ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor  
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillium dolore 
          eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
      </div> <!-- #content -->

      <div id="footer">
         &copy; Copyright RGB 2015
      </div>

    </div> <!-- #page -->

  </body>
</html>
```

---

#### Minimal snippet with `phone.css`

As per [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28718058/477035) of [Michael Kampmann Rasm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4045474/michael-kampmann-rasmussen). However I'm having trouble getting the inner divs to fill the width of `div#page`.

```css
body { 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
  background: grey;
}

#page {
  background: lightgrey;
  margin: 2em auto;

  //display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* optional */
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -moz-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;

}

#header, #navigation, #content, #footer {
  background: white;
  padding: 0.7em;
}
#navigation, #content, #footer {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

#header { 
  font-size: 3em; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  color: red;
  //width: 87.3%;

  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  order: 1;

}

#navigation {
  // width: 95.8%;
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;
  -ms-flex-order: 3;
  -webkit-order: 3;
  order: 3;
}
#navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
#navigation li {
  display:inline;
}

#content {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  -ms-flex-order: 2;
  -webkit-order: 2;
  order: 2;

}
#content td:first-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}
#content td {
  padding: 0 0.5em 0.2em 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#footer {
  //width: 95.8%;
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 4;
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 4;
  -ms-flex-order: 4;
  -webkit-order: 4;
  order: 4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>layout & font-size tests</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page">
  
      <div id="header">
        Site Name
      </div>

      <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li>Here</li>
          <li>There</li>
          <li>Somewhere</li>
          <li>Elsewhere</li>
          <li>Hither</li>
          <li>Thither</li>
          <li>Yon</li>
          <li>Beyond</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div id="content">
        <h1>Welcome to Site Name!</h1>
        <h2>Diary</h2>
        <table class="calendar">
          <tr><td>Jun 18 2015</td><td>18:30</td><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Jul 01 2015</td><td>09:00</td><td>consectetur adipisicing elit</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Aug 09 2015</td><td>18:00</td>
              <td>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
                  magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud   
                  exercitation exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip</td></tr>
        </table>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p>
          dolor sit amet,  consectetur adipisicing      
          elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
          magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud   
          exercitation exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip 
          ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor  
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillium dolore 
          eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p>
          dolor sit amet,  consectetur adipisicing      
          elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
          magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud   
          exercitation exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip 
          ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor  
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillium dolore 
          eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
      </div> <!-- #content -->

      <div id="footer">
         &copy; Copyright RGB 2015
      </div>

    </div> <!-- #page -->

  </body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: Can you create a demo fiddle which you tried sofar?

Comment: @Etash: Snippets added. Michael's answer has put me on the right track though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 767px){
     #page {
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -moz-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
            -moz-box-orient: vertical;
            -webkit-flex-direction: column;
            -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
            /* optional */
            -webkit-box-align: start;
            -moz-box-align: start;
            -ms-flex-align: start;
            -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
            align-items: flex-start;
     }
     #header {
            -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
            -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
            -ms-flex-order: 1;
            -webkit-order: 1;
            order: 1;
     }
     #content {
            -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
            -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
            -ms-flex-order: 2;
            -webkit-order: 2;
            order: 2;
     }
     #navigation {
            -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
            -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;
            -ms-flex-order: 3;
            -webkit-order: 3;
            order: 3;
     }
     #footer {
            -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 4;
            -moz-box-ordinal-group: 4;
            -ms-flex-order: 4;
            -webkit-order: 4;
            order: 4;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This thing is pretty simple to do, **you have to think the normal HTML float**. I assume you use HTML code looks like this :

```
<div class="nav"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

With some CSS like this :

```
.nav {float: left;}
.content {float: right;}
```

So, *HTML normal float will make your .nav element go before the .content element (as it comes before in the DOM)*.

So, simply :

```
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="nav"></div>
```

And use the same CSS ( set .nav to float left, and .content to float right).

Then, **on mobile breakpoint**, set them both to `float: none;`

**To achieve that with pure CSS, you can use Flexbox**, but you have to consider its implementation : http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox (IE10+)

Comment: caniuse.com looks very useful. Thanks.